# What is the Big O run time complexity of O(C(n,r)^2)?

Tags: algorithm

I have code that runs in `O(C(n,r)^2)` complexity.

I realize that  `C(n,r) = n! / ( r! (n - r)! )` but is this really a `n!` time complexity? The `r` value makes this a factorial complexity but the `n` value changes the complexity more like an `O(n^x)` given a constant `r`.

So does having a static `r` value and dynamic `n` value make this solution a `O(n^x)` or an `O(n!)` solution?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O(_) denotes a family (a set, an equivalence class) of functions of a single variable. If you want to consider the asymptotic growth of n^r as a function of n, that variable is n. If you wanted to consider it as a function of r, it would be r. In both cases, the other variable would of course influence the shape of this set of functions of the first variable. E.g. for r=2 the set would be O(n^2) and for r=3 it would be O(n^3), in general O(n^r).

Answer (score 4):

Let's first look at `O( C(n,r) ) = O( n! / (r! (n-r)!) )`.

For a **constant** `r`, we have:

```
O( C(n,r) ) = O( n! / (r! (n-r)!) ) = O( n! / (n-r)! )
            = O( n*(n-1)*...*(n-r+1) ) = O( n^r )
```

Thus:

```
O( C(n,r)^2 ) = O( n^(2r) )
```

Answer (score 2):

For a fixed `r`, the complexity class is `O(n^r)`.